# Audio PWM on atmega644

Tags: avr, c, pwm

I'm trying to generate audio through a 3.5mm jack using an atmega644. I tried following [this tutorial](http://avrpcm.blogspot.com/2010/11/playing-8-bit-pcm-using-any-avr.html), but even with the sampling provided, I only get a high-pitched whine. I did a lot of reading in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2593.pdf) and came up with this code:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "pcm_sample.h"
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#define SAMPLE_RATE 8000;

volatile uint16_t sample = 0;

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
    if (sample >= pcm_length) {
        sample = 0;
    }
    OCR1A = pcm_samples[sample++];
}

void init(void) {
    DDRD = (1<<PD5); // OCR1A

    // Fast PWM Mode 14, TOP=ICR1(0x7D), toggle OC1A on compare match
    TCCR1A = (1<<COM1A1) |  (1<<WGM11); 
    TCCR1B = (1<<CS10) | (1<<WGM12) | (1<<WGM13);
    TIMSK1 = (1<<TOIE1); // Interrupt on overflow
    // Timer ticks at 1us, samples every 125us, so overflow every 125us
    ICR1 = 0x7D; // Overflow at 125
    OCR1A = pcm_samples[0]; // Set initial duty
    sei();
}

int main(void) {
    init();
    while (1);
}
```

But then nothing comes out of the headphone jack. My first thought was that the interrupt isn't firing, but I'm pretty sure it's set up right. Any ideas?

EDIT: The WGM12 bit is in the TCCR1B register and timer 1 needs a clock source, as Bruce Abbot pointed out below. I've changed this in the code and now the interrupt fires, however it still doesn't play the sound. Instead I get a high pitched whine and occasionally broken by a thumping noise.

Also, I realized that the timing was probably off, so I've changed I did some maths and came up with the above (hopefully it's correct). It required I be able to set when Timer 1 overflowed, so I've change from using Mode 5 to Mode 14. After correcting some math mistakes, it is improving: fuzzy noise instead of a high-pitched whine.

The solution to this was a combination of the below answers and comments. The code above is working, although it's pretty low quality you can clearly hear "It's working" (for this application, I'm not bothered about the quality, but I assume to fix that you just need to look into a higher sample rate as Chris Stratton mentions below). Thanks to all those who helped.

Comment: when debugging, to know if micro controller has gone over a specific line, add a line after that line which blinks an led or something.

Comment: @BlueSky I've tried this, init is definitely called and run, but the interrupt is never triggered

Comment: Try to avoid dividing by 255 - it's probably not what you want anyway, and dividing by 256 as an 8 bit shift (or more realistically, only using the high byte) is far, far faster.

Comment: @ChrisStratton OK, it appears I'm missing something fundamental in my understanding of PWM (judging from all the answers and comments below). Tell me where I'm wrong here: all I'm trying to do is make a digital signal kind of act like an analogue signal by toggling a pin quickly; the numbers in the sample array represent the hight of the wave at that point in time, and match up with how long I need to keep the pin high before toggling it off for the remaining part of that interval

Comment: Divide an 8 bit integer by 255 and then multiply it by 128, what do you get? For any number less than 255, Zero! You are trying to use the same timer both for producing PWM and setting the sample rate, which won't work properly. You should use a separate sample playback timer. The ATmega644 only has 4k of RAM, so by having the sample data in RAM rather than ROM you are limited to 0.5s maximum playback time. I suggest that you go back to the original tutorial code and just make the few changes required to suit your MCU.

Answer (score 1):

Your interrupt vector is incorrect.  The ISR routine looking for TIMER0_1VF_vect although you never set up the TIMER0 timer and TIMER0_1VF_vect isn't a valid vector according to [atmels list](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__interrupts.html).

You set up the TIMER1 to interrupt on overflow so you should use the TIMER1_OVF_vect instead which will trigger on TIMER1 overflow

Comment: Sorry, that was an error in copying my code over, it's correct in the code I've been using

Comment: @TheBeanstalk it doesn't work with that fix?  Can you post the pcm_samples then?  I'm wondering if your pcm_samples is too large to fit into the OCR1A register alone.  OCR1 is actually 16-bits split across OCR1A and OCR1B

Comment: the pcm_samples are the same ones used in the first tutorial (they're a little long to post here). I've checked and they're all less than one byte (255, 0xFF).

Comment: Alright then you may be running into a Catch-all interrupt issue then.  Basically when you have enabled more interrupts than you have ISRs for, the whole program resets and calls main again.
Check out the catch-all section of this: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html#_details

Comment: @TheBeanstalk I retrieved this info from here: 
http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/seems-while1-loop-not-working

Comment: @TheBeanstalk  if this doesn't help then I'm out of ideas, at which point I'll delete my answer since it is no longer helpful

Comment: This is really useful for making sure I'm using the right interrupt vector, but it didn't solve the problem unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

```
#define SAMPLE_RATE 8000;
```

Apart from any other issues you might have, a sample rate of 8 KSPS is well within the audible range and readily meets the description of "a high pitched whine".

To use such a low sample rate without the framing being audible will require an external low pass filter with sufficient roll-off to attenuate the framing, which will substantially curtail your audio bandwidth - basically, if you implement it right you might be left with "telephone" class bandwidth.

To do PWM audio, you probably want a higher frame rate.  The ATtiny family can do PWM with an imprecise ~64 MHz clock rate multiplied up from the internal oscillator.  Various ARM parts can with a rate multiplied up from a more precise external crystal.

Comment: But as long as I'm not using samples from a sine wave, shouldn't I get something other than a constant tone?

Comment: You may get something else as well, but unless your PWM duty cycle is 100% or is fully filtered, you will hear the 8 KHz PWM itself.

Comment: This got me thinking about the timer and clock speeds, and I realized they didn't line up. Would changing the rate at which the timer overflows to match the sample rate (as above) fix this problem?

Comment: No, only moving the PWM frame rate above audible frequency or a filter cutoff would prevent the PWM frame rate from being audible.  Of course you may well have other problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a clock source for Timer 0. In the ATmega644 this is selected by bits 2:0 of TCCR0B, so add the following line to your `init()` function:-

```
TCCR0B = (1<<CS00);
```

PWM mode bit WGM12 is in register TCCRnB (not TTCRnA), and you also need to select a clock source for PWM. So change this:-

```
TCCR1A = (1<<COM1A1) | (1<<WGM12) | (1<<WGM10);
```

to this:-

```
TCCR1A = (1<<COM1A1) | (1<<WGM10);
TCCR1B = (1<<WGM12) | (1<<CS10);
```

Finally, you need to enable overflow interrupts on Timer 0 (not timer 1) so change:-

```
TIMSK1 = (1<<TOIE1); // Interrupt on overflow
```

to:-

```
TIMSK0 = (1<<TOIE0); // Interrupt on Timer 0 overflow
```

This should get the interrupt firing.

However if your sample data is stored in Flash ROM (PROGMEM) you may find that it doesn't play properly. Program memory is in a different address space and needs special code to access it, so you may have to use the function `pgm_read_byte()` to tell the compiler to generate the correct instructions, like this:-

```
OCR1A = pgm_read_byte(&(pcm_samples[sample++]));
```

Comment: I've deviated slightly from the tutorial linked in my question and haven't stored the sample data in PROGMEM, so just setting OCR1A to ppm_samples[sample] should work, right?

Comment: Why does he need to set up the Timer 0 instead of Timer 1 if he is filling in the TCCR1A/B registers?  It seems like you're filling in both sets of TIMER registers about half-way.  OP is already filling in the clock source bit and all the bits you note for TIMER1...

Comment: @Beanstalk yes.

Comment: I didn't notice that you had edited your code. ISR vector should be TIMER0_**O**VF_vect like in the tutorial. Timer 0 is used to play back the samples at 8000Hz. Timer 1 is assigned to PWM period, which operates at a higher frequency.

Comment: So on the hardware side, do I keep the jack hooked up to OCR1A, or do I need to move it to OCR0A?

Comment: You hook the jack up to OC1A (PD5) because that is where the PWM comes out. This is using timer 1 (TCCR1A, OCR1A etc.).

Comment: I guess I'm confused why timer0 is needed then... Timer1 is set up to toggle PD5 when it reaches whatever is in the OCR1A register, and also to trigger an overflow interrupt when it reaches 0xFF right? Isn't that all I need to generate the audio?

Comment: No. PWM needs to run at a much higher frequency than the sample rate, or else you get a full voltage 8000Hz square wave which will make a terrible whining noise. Even if the PWM timer does overflow (which it won't if configured for 8 bit PWM) the interrupt frequency will be wrong. You must use a separate timer to generate the 8000 interrupts per second required to play the samples at the correct rate.